# Loop through table and select 100 rows, then the next 100 rows..etc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server which it contains ids for items, and they're not unique in that table. I am trying to pass it to an `openquery` to grab additional information for these items from oracle.

The table can have 5000-17000 row at a time. I tried to convert all the rows for that column to a comma separated string and then pass it to the open query

```
declare @results varchar(max)

set @results = (select stuff([list],1,3,'') as stuff_list
                from (select '''''' + ',' + '''''' + cast(itemId as varchar(10)) as [text()]
                      from ItemTable sub
                      order by itemId asc
                      for xml path('')) sub_query([list]) )
```

then pass it to the openquery

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

SET @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(op, ''SELECT * FROM ITEM_INFO WHERE ITEM_CODE IN('+@results+')'')'

--SET @SQL = @SQL + 'WHERE ITEM_CODE IN(' + @results  +')'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

I get:

> The character string that starts with 'SELECT * FROM.....' is too long. Maximum length is 8000.

So I thought I might be able to loop through the table and select 100 rows at a time and then pass it to the open query and so on. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: The `plsql` tag really doesn't belong here, if you're talking about SQL Server. PL/SQL is the **Oracle** procedural SQL language "dialect" .....

Comment: Tables don't have "records"; they have rows and columns.

Comment: Always specify the version in your tags. If this is earlier version of SQL Server, you can use offset_fetch. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: At some point you'll be better-off just running `SELECT * FROM ITEM_INFO` and filtering on the SQL Server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage EXEC AT [LinkedServer] to overcome the limitation of 8000 characters.

Here, the datatype is MAX datatype, so you dont have 8000 character issue.

[EXEC at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> @string_variable Is the name of a local variable. @string_variable can
> be any char, varchar, nchar, or nvarchar data type. These include the
> (max) data types.

```sql
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ITEM_INFO WHERE ITEM_CODE IN('+@results+')'

EXEC (@SQL) AT op
```

**REFERENCES**

- You can also dynamically pass parameters. [More info](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1757/dynamic-sql-execution-on-remote-sql-server-using-exec-at/)
- [technet article for EXEC AT](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36213.sql-server-execute-at-linkedserver.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately EXEC AT does not allow to insert the result in some table :/